# is null conditional operator is expensive to use over and over

Tags: c#

I have written logic as below.

```
 return new Notification() {
            ChannelId = data?.Channel?.ChannelID,
            GatewayType = data?.Channel?.PrimaryGW?.Type,
            PaymentMethod = data?.GatewayTransaction?.PaymentMethodTypes.ToString(),
            PaymentType = data?.GatewayTransaction?.PaymentType.ToString(),
            Data = data,
        };
```

The ?. operator is being repeated on the same object on each line. But is it too expensive to put ?. every where rather than writing logic as below?

```
var notification = new Notification();
        if (data != null)
        {
            if (data.Channel != null)
            {
                notification.ChannelId = data.Channel.ChannelID;
                notification.GatewayType = data.Channel.PrimaryGW.Type;
            }
            if (data.GatewayTransaction != null)
            {
                notification.PaymentMethod = data.GatewayTransaction.PaymentMethodTypes.ToString();
                notification.PaymentType = data.GatewayTransaction.PaymentType.ToString();
            }

            notification.Data = data;
        }
        return notification;
```

As a lazy developers we do put ?. operator every where to escape from writing if statements. But is it cost us like in the above scenarios?

Comment: What do you mean by "expensive"?

Comment: You could inspect the IL generated by the two an compare (you may be surprised)

Comment: Consider the alternative `ChannelId = ((data == null) ? null : data.Channel == null) ? null) : data.Channel.ChannelID)` (I think that's right). Or `if (data == null || data.Channel == null) { ChanneId = null; } else { ChannelId = ChannelID; }`. That's pretty much what the compiler transpiles your `.?` code into

Comment: There is no runtime cost difference between using the null conditional operator and writing the equivalent null check in a longer form.

Comment: @JonathanDodds here the null operator is being repeated on each line. That is why i am thinking it might expensive wrt to performance.        
              ChannelId = data?.Channel?.ChannelID,
            GatewayType = data?.Channel?.PrimaryGW?.Type,

Comment: @ChandraMohan Yes, I missed that point. I don't know how the compiler will optimize that but inspecting the IL will show it. It would not surprise me if the compiler recognizes that a given null check (e.g. `data?.`) can be done once. I just don't know without performing the experiment.

Comment: You probably would not see that `data?.` optimization in the IL. That seems (to me) like the kind of optimization that the JITter would do. I may be wildly wrong though

Comment: I doubt the performance difference is going to be noticable. `data` will end up in a register, so you are looking at a bunch of `test jz` instruction pairs, and some extra store operations. But unless you are doing this in an exceedingly tight loop you will not notice.

Answer (score 0):

This code (I simplify for the example) :

```cs
var notification = new Notification() {
    ChannelId = data?.ChannelID
};
```

It's equivalent to

```cs
var notification = new Notification();
if(data != null)
{
    notification.ChannelID = data.ChannelID;
}
else
{
    notification.ChannelID = null;
}
```

`notification.ChannelID` is set in all case.

With the code :

```cs
var notification = new Notification();
if(data != null)
{
    notification.ChannelID = data.ChannelID;
}
```

`notification.ChannelID` is set only when data isn't null.

Then the code is more speed (when `data` is null), but I don't consider it less expensive because it don't cover all functionality from the original code.

Answer (score 0):

As per suggestions, I have viewed the IL generated code .

```
Notification notification = new Notification();
    object channelId;
    if (data == null)
    {
        channelId = null;
    }
    else
    {
        Channel channel = data.Channel;
        channelId = ((channel != null) ? channel.ChannelID : null);
    }
    notification.ChannelId = (string)channelId;
    object gatewayType;
    if (data == null)
    {
        gatewayType = null;
    }
    else
    {
        Channel channel2 = data.Channel;
        if (channel2 == null)
        {
            gatewayType = null;
        }
        else
        {
            Gateway primaryGW = channel2.PrimaryGW;
            gatewayType = ((primaryGW != null) ? primaryGW.Type : null);
        }
    }
    notification.GatewayType = (string)gatewayType;
    object paymentMethod;
    if (data == null)
    {
        paymentMethod = null;
    }
    else
    {
        GatewayTransaction gatewayTransaction = data.GatewayTransaction;
        paymentMethod = ((gatewayTransaction != null) ? gatewayTransaction.PaymentMethodTypes.ToString() : null);
    }
    notification.PaymentMethod = (string)paymentMethod;
    object paymentType;
    if (data == null)
    {
        paymentType = null;
    }
    else
    {
        GatewayTransaction gatewayTransaction2 = data.GatewayTransaction;
        paymentType = ((gatewayTransaction2 != null) ? gatewayTransaction2.PaymentType.ToString() : null);
    }
    notification.PaymentType = (string)paymentType;
    notification.Data = data;
    return notification;
```

As expected the IL is generating if and else statements for each null condition operation. That is what i wanted to avoid as the above if else can be optimized which will reduces the few if else statements as below.

```
var notification = new Notification();
if (data != null)
    {
        if (data.Channel != null)
        {
            notification.ChannelId = data.Channel.ChannelID;
            notification.GatewayType = data.Channel.PrimaryGW.Type;
        }
        if (data.GatewayTransaction != null)
        {
            notification.PaymentMethod = data.GatewayTransaction.PaymentMethodTypes.ToString();
            notification.PaymentType = data.GatewayTransaction.PaymentType.ToString();
        }
    }
    return notification;
```

This will reduce the number of lines of code and might increase the performance in tight loop.